# What is the structural behaviour of SSIS in it's Pre-execute phase of package execution ? Why the heavy packages hangs in Pre-Execute phase?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

The poor production database schema directs me to do multiple left joins, Left join with range condition in on clause and character column joins.

Even though my packages is free from errors, it is hanging in Pre-execute phase.

I read many articles online which tells about how to prevent this. such as `Delay validation`, `External metadata` , ... etc.

So please help me to know what is the work of data flow,control flow and sql server engine in Pre-execute phase ?

Comment: Without more details it can only be guessed that it takes all the time to validate. Delaying validation will not help speeding up package execution because it just *delays until executing*. Depending on whether you run your package from SSIS-Catalog or File System, check the log output to find out which parts take longest to validate.

Answer (score 4):

It's always a good idea to [enable logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/performance/integration-services-ssis-logging) in your SSIS packages.  Without logging, it can be hard to determine exactly what SSIS did, especially if your packages are executed overnight by a task scheduler!

To enable; right click, on the [control flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/control-flow), and select *logging...* from the menu.  A [dialog will open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/performance/configure-ssis-logs-dialog-box).  You can use this screen to configure where the data is logged (Windows Event Log, SQL Server, Text File, etc) and what is logged.

I would recommend you log everything.  The output can be quite verbose.  I'm afraid reading the SSIS logs is an acquired skill.  There is a lot of detail, which you need, but that can make it hard to find the exact row(s) you are interested in.  There is no shortcut here, you will need to roll your sleeves up and get stuck in.

Packages that contain a lot of connections can take a while to get through pre-execution.  I've noticed packages with lots of connections to the file system are especially slow.

**EDIT**
I've just noticed I didn't actually answer the OPs question.  So here goes...

Although SSIS appears to be frozen/hung it probably isn't.  Log everything and review to fix.  You can view the log *in-flight*, which helps.